# Google My Business Pub/Sub Notifications Not Working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-reviews

I am trying to get Review notifications to an external server, without success.
I have currently set up a topic with a Push subscription towards my endpoint, but I can't get Google to publish notifications to said topic: I have used [this](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/notifications/rest/v1/accounts/updateNotificationSetting) API to set my account's notification settings, and whenever I retrieve the current notificationSettings I get the following response:

```
{
    "name": "accounts/myAccId/notificationSetting",
    "pubsubTopic": "projects/myProjName/topics/myTopicName",
    "notificationTypes": [
        "GOOGLE_UPDATE",
        "NEW_REVIEW",
        "UPDATED_REVIEW"
    ]
}
```

Despite this, whenever I leave a review (with a different google account) under one of the locations managed/owned by my Business Account, no notification arrives to my external endpoint.

I might also add that I already gave **mybusiness-api-pubsub@system.gserviceaccount.com** (exactly as written here) Pub/Sub Publisher role for my topic, and that my topic correctly delivers when testing manually.

Am I missing something? Or is there any way I can get some kind of logs and see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Go to topic that you made and in principles give permmission to all users and then try